# Access Report, print pdf per group

Tags: loops, ms-access, vba, pdf-generation, ms-access-2007

I am still fairly new to VBA. I have been racking my brains, looked into every forum trying to find how to do this. This is the closest I have got so far.
I have a table called Streets which a report is based on, showing number of houses per street. Each record is on a single page on a report called StreetPrintOuts. I have the streets split into different regions, and those regions (MapNum) are all numbered. I want each pdf to show all the street records of each street in it's region. So far I have this:

```
Public Sub PDFGroup_Click()
Const Folder = "C:\Users\Records\"
Const Domain = "Streets"
'Domain can be table name, query name, or sql statement that provides the values to loop
Const LoopedField = "MapNum"
Const ReportName = "StreetPrintOuts"

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim LoopedFieldValue As Long
Dim FileName As String
Dim FullPath As String
Dim strWhere As String
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Domain)

Do While Not rs.EOF
LoopedFieldValue = rs.Fields(LoopedField)
FileName = LoopedFieldValue & ".pdf"
'The field may be a text field. It then must be surrounded in singlequotes. If so uncomment below
'LoopedFieldValue = "'" & LoopedFieldValue & "'"
FullPath = Folder & FileName
strWhere = LoopedField & " = " & LoopedFieldValue
Debug.Print FullPath
Debug.Print strWhere
DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName, acViewPreview, , strWhere
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, ReportName, acFormatPDF, FullPath
DoCmd.Close acReport, ReportName
rs.MoveNext
Loop

End Sub
```

Every time it runs, it stops after

```
DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName, acViewPreview, , strWhere
```

With error code Runtime 2501 error: outputto action was canceled

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This code actually does work. I had left in another variable making it break elsewhere in the report. Obviously working too late into the night and missing things.